# Delay between start and end of the RAM

Tags: memory

Is the delay the same when a CPU needs to go to the start of the RAM or the end, or there is no difference?

Comment: That's hardly a question about programming in C. :) Interesting, though.

Comment: Depends on what you consider "RAM". The "RAM" a process sees or the physical "RAM" a box provides.

Comment: It depends on the structure of the RAM and memory space. For example, a processor with L1/L2/L3 SRAM and SDRAM basically has 4 different delays for 4 different address regions. Also for NUMA architecture, the processor cluster has lower latency accessing the memory attached closer to it. Adapteva Epiphany/Parallella is similar, and has a linear latency increase depending on the distance of processor and memory. Also if you consider GPU memory as RAM, then device memory mapped to host address space also has a longer latency. So, the latency varies but not necessarily that simple

Comment: You need to be more specific. Taking the simplest case, a single memory chip addressed by a simple CPU, no; the mechanism used to decode the memory location would make access time uniform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference in performance when the CPU tries to access physical memory at some arbitrary address/range.

As far as the CPU is concerned, it's interacting with a memory controller over a bus. The values in *random access* memory are retrieved by means of an address without having to be concerned about *where* the address happens to be physically located within a memory module.

If we assume the CPU is requesting contents located in RAM after cache misses, then it doesn't matter if the requested address is `x` or `x + 100`. The time delays are expected to be within the same performance range.

The 'start' and 'end' locations would matter if you were to switch to media based on *sequential* access (e.g. tape drives, often used for backups).

Note that I'm avoiding the topic of a process' view of memory when executed by the OS (e.g. virtual memory, etc) and also the idea of trying different kinds/amounts of memory being tested and compared against each other. In other words, I'm assuming that a given system has a fixed amount of a given memory type for a given test.

In addition, when looking at memory module specs, I've never noticed any information indicating some sort of performance penalty/gain if a certain address range within the modulewere to be avoided/used.

Comment: So for example, CPU needs to access for a next address in RAM, it will take the same time than ten addresses further, right? I would like to be sure it does not exist any kind of cache or other "quick ways" to access, like Disk cache for example.

Comment: @Kdmeizk I'm not clear on what you mean there. Systems cache data to improve performance. The CPU has several levels of cache. If I understand what you mean correctly, then presumably, if the CPU is trying to access RAM data after cache misses, then it doesn't matter if it's trying to access address `x` or `x+10`. I'm also assuming you're not talking about the speed at which it would be processed, since pipelined CPUs fetch/process data in chunks, but if it needs something else (e.g. due to a branch) then pipeline may need to be flushed and takes a performance hit.

Comment: "_if the CPU is trying to access RAM data after cache misses, then it doesn't matter if it's trying to access address x or x+10_" Yes I wanted to know mainly for this. Thank you all for answers in spite of my clarity.

Comment: @Kdmeizk Sounds good. I've updated my answer with what I clarified in the comments section.